# how to end a loop when a random number reaches 0

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, time

I'm not great at python and couldn't find a solution that i could understand.
I'm trying to get the program to output "random timer has ended" once a random countdown has finished.

```
import time
from random import randint

RandomTimer = randint(1,10) #picks random number of seconds for countdown
while RandomTimer > 0:
    time.sleep(1)
    RandomTimer - 1  #reduces random number every second until it reaches 0
print("random timer ended")
```

The code here doesn't work as the countdown never seems to finish, even after 10 seconds. I know there's something i'm doing wrong but can figure it out.

Comment: You need to update the variable, like `RandomTimer = RandomTimer - 1` or `RandomTimer -= 1`. In your code you are just computing the new value, but never really assigning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update `RandomTimer`:

```
import time
from random import randint

RandomTimer = randint(1,10)
while RandomTimer > 0:
    time.sleep(1)
    RandomTimer -= 1
print("random timer ended")
```

the above code change the line `RandomTimer - 1` to `RandomTimer -= 1`

Answer (score 0):

In Python a variable holds a reference to an object.

To "change" a variable, you may either change the referenced object. Or reference an other object.
You are not updating the variable:

> "in place" update:

```
import time
from random import randint

RandomTimer = randint(1,10) #picks random number of seconds for countdown
while RandomTimer > 0:
    time.sleep(1)
    RandomTimer -= 1  #reduces random number every second until it reaches 0
print("random timer ended")
```

or create a new reference :

```
RandomTimer = randint(1,10) #picks random number of seconds for countdown
while RandomTimer > 0:
    time.sleep(1)
    RandomTimer = RandomTimer -1  #reduces random number every second until it reaches 0
print("random timer ended")
```